# Continuous Audio Playback with Sounddevice

Tags: python, linux, python-sounddevice

I am writing a program to stream audio over a network, so I have a thread to record data and one to send it. When testing the audio has noticeable gaps. I beleive this is due to the `sounddevice.play()` function, the example below has the same problem.

```
import sounddevice as sd

len = 5
fs = 44100
sd.default.device = [2,1]

myrec=sd.rec(int(fs*len), samplerate=fs, channels=2, blocking=True) #fill an array with some sound
while True:
    sd.play(myrec, blocking=True)
    #loop plays 5 second audio clip with slight gaps
```

The gaps coincide with the play length, so it appears to be caused by a delay in the play function. In continious audio this becomes very noticeable and annoying. The same thing also happens in the documentation audio passthrough example [here](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.1/examples.html#input-to-output-pass-through).

Is there any was to make the playback continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `sd.play()` is not meant to be used repeatedly in rapid succession. Internally, it each time creates an `sd.OutputStream`, plays the audio data and closes the stream again.
Because of opening and closing the stream, gaps will occur. This is expected.

For continuous playback you should use the [sd.OutputStream.write()](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.1/index.html#sounddevice.Stream.write) function or, even better, an `sd.OutputStream` with a custom callback function (as shown in some of the example programs).

> The same thing also happens in the documentation audio passthrough example [here](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.2.1/examples.html#input-to-output-pass-through).

This must have a different reason. This should work, and it works fine for me.
Can you please describe the problem in more detail? Are there any messages printed to the terminal?

Comment: When I use the wire.py example I call it using `python3 wire.py -i 2 -o 1 -c 2 -s 44100` which doesn't provide and audio output. If I use the -l argument with value 1 I heard the mic audio with a 1s delay, but there is a noticeable pause ever ~5s. I can ignore -l and use -b 8192 which gives lower latency playback, but still with the noticeable gaps ~5/6s. The only error I get is when I press return to end I see `WARNING:root:input overflow, output underflow`

Comment: Using the above code but replacing the stream as you suggested I get the following errors:
`sd.OutputStream.write(myrec)` gives: TypeError: write() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'


and trying:
`stream = sd.OutputStream(samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float32')`
`stream.write(myrec)`
gives the error: sounddevice.PortAudioError: Stream is stopped [PaErrorCode -9983]

Comment: The pauses you are describing are strange, I don't know what's going wrong there. For the other problem, you'll have to `start()` the stream (either explicitly or in a `with` statement).

Comment: Ahhh, of course. That worked and it sounds like there is no gap. The example code in the docs still isn't working, but at least I can play my audio buffers without gaps. Thanks.

Comment: the pauses seem to only happen on the Linux VM I was working in, otherwise it works properly.